# Remove quotes surrounding number

Tags: regex, linux, sed, numbers

I have a file with the lines looking similar to:

```
"somestring": "20.000",
```

I want to remove the quotes around 20.000.

Other use cases are

```
"somestring": "20",
"somestring": "blahhhah 3",
"somestring": "",
```

which should give

```
"somestring": 20,
"somestring": "blahhhah 3",
"somestring": "",
```

Obvious regex to recognize numbers is `[0-9]+` and `[0-9].[0-9]+` for decimals. 
I was told this is possible with the sed command as it can backreference, however I do not know how to use the sed command.
Can someone please provide me with any linux command to accomplish this?

Comment: _...however I do not know how to use the sed command_ [Here you go.](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ sed -r 's@"([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?)",\s*$@\1,@' file
"somestring": 20.000,
"somestring": 20,
"somestring": "blahhhah 3",
"somestring": "",
```

Comment: What about this `"somestring": "20.000",` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/"([[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+){0,1})"/\1/' file
"somestring": 20,
"somestring": "blahhhah 3",
"somestring": "",
"somestring": 20.000,
```

On OSX use:

```
sed -E 's/"([[:digit:]]+(\.[[:digit:]]+){0,1})"/\1/'
```

Answer (score 0):

In basic mode:

```
sed 's/^\("[^"]*": \)"\([0-9][0-9]*\(\.[0-9]*\)\?\)"/\1\2/' file.txt
```